# Python Get Charts in Google Sheet and copy in Google Slides

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-slides

I have a google sheet that have some predefined charts and I inject data via API to update those charts. Now I want to copy those charts to Google Slides:

My code:

```
try:
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
    rangeName = "opiniones!A2:I" + str(len(data)+1)
    Body = {
        'values': data,
    }

    # Escribimos los datos en la hoja
    service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=file_copy_id, 
                                           range=rangeName,
                                           valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
                                           body=Body).execute()

    # insertamos la relación de tipos de restaurante con su media comparando
    # con su valoracion el rango es desde la posición 27 hasta la 27+longitud
    # de lista+1 pues la primera posición de lista es la 0
    rangeName = "datos!B27:E" + str(27+len(restaurantTypes)+1)
    Body = {
       'values': restaurantTypes
    }

    service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=file_copy_id,
                                           range=rangeName,
                                           valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
                                           body=Body).execute()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Any idea on how to copy an already defined chart?

Thank you!

Comment: Does [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts) help?

Comment: Thank you. That's great to create charts via API, anyway, maybe to get the Chart ID I can use:GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId?fields=sheets(charts) but not sure how to invoke that API via Python: service.speradsheets().values().......

Comment: How do you want to copy the charts? As an image or as linked object? The latter is currently not possible.

Comment: As linked object. I did it already using Sheets and Slides APIs. Thank you

Comment: If you did it already,  what is then your question about?

Comment: I did it after publishing the help request.....